# What's the difference between account expiry(inactive) and account becoming locked?

Tags: users, password

[image]

Source: https://linuxopsys.com/topics/chage-command-in-linux

[image]

**The image is taken from the book Linux with Operating System Concepts.**

What I don't understand here is that what is `-E` option?

Is it the date when password expires or account becomes inactive?

What's the difference between account expiry and account becoming inactive?

From the man pages:

```
-E, --expiredate EXPIRE_DATE
           Set the date or number of days since January 1, 1970 on which the user's account
           will no longer be accessible. The date may also be expressed in the format
           YYYY-MM-DD (or the format more commonly used in your area). A user whose account is
           locked must contact the system administrator before being able to use the system
           again.


-I, --inactive INACTIVE
           Set the number of days of inactivity after a password has expired before the
           account is locked. The INACTIVE option is the number of days of inactivity. A user
           whose account is locked must contact the system administrator before being able to
           use the system again.
```

The confusion exists between -E and -I option.

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/108618).

Comment: I don't know where your second screenshot is from, the linked site doesn't have a "table 9.4". But https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/4/html/system_administration_guide/s2-redhat-config-users-passwd-aging and https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lunar/en/man1/chage.1.html both say `-E` is for the date on which the account becomes locked.

Comment: Dear achhainsan, welcome to this site! Please don't feel terrified by being confronted with site rules and someone downvoting your question. There just are some best practices that make this place as useful as it is, and it is not intended to sound unfriendly when teaching those things. Soon you can feel at home here anyhow and understand this. I hope, @muru's comment answers your question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Where, exactly, were those phrases "account expiry" and "account becoming inactive" appear? Is there some reason to assume they mean different things to begin with?

Comment: I'll also note what was mentioned in an earlier comment: the site you link to doesn't seem to contain that table. It does contain other text, though. It would make it easier to figure out what you're asking if you quoted the text you're actually referring to (with links, so that it'd be possible to check the context, too)

Comment: The quote says _"-E: set the day on which the user's account will become inactive (will expire)"_. That rather clearly seems to answer both of your questions: it's the date when the account becomes inactive (nothing mentioned of the password), and it draws a clear equality between "inactivation" and "expiry". (Expiration is something that happens due to time passing, like the way your milk can get expired if you forget it in the fridge. If an administrator disables an account explicitly, I wouldn't see that called "expiring" it (it might mean something else as a euphemism, though.))

Comment: I've updated the question with the best I could do @everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the confusion is due to two different things that might expire: the account, and its password.

Consider the following sequence of events:

1. The account is created at time T<sub>0</sub>.
2. It is set to expire at time T<sub>e</sub> using the `-E` option.
3. A password is set on the account.
4. The password is set to expire at time T<sub>p</sub> using the `-M` option.
5. The account is set to lock at some time dT after the password expires using the `-I` option.

Then:

- T<sub>e</sub> is unrelated to and independent of T<sub>p</sub> and dT.
- The account can get locked at the earlier of T<sub>e</sub> (locked due account expiration) and T<sub>m</sub> = T<sub>p</sub> + dT (locked due to inactivity after password expiration).

Now, *inactive* can mean multiple things. It can mean that there is no *activity* on the account, so no one has logged into it. It can mean that the account is no longer available, so no one *can* log into it. Which meaning is used depends on the context.

- During the time between T<sub>p</sub> and T<sub>m</sub>, the account is inactive - no one has logged into it.
- After T<sub>m</sub> or T<sub>e</sub>, the account is also inactive, but because no one can log into it.